# insert/create new row in a same section of uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, insert, row, nsindexpath

I am stuck in a problem, I have a uitableview with rows let say 5. 
If a user selects one row then a new row exactly beneath the tapped row should be created/inserted with an animation (as we have seen with sections hiding/unhiding) and upon tap of the newly inserted row it should be deleted.

I have given a try but it says

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid  
update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section 
after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update 
(5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'
```

so what should be the other way to achieve this functionality ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return numberOfRows;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    numberOfRows ++;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    NSMutableArray*  tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [tempArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row +1  inSection:indexPath.section]];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tableView endUpdates]; 
    [tempArray release];

}
```

I was making 2 mistakes 
1) I wasnot using  [tableView beginUpdates] and obviously [tableView endUpdates] after updation
2) The method to calculate the indexpath for a newRow was ambigious.

Thankyou very much pratikshabhisikar and Max Howell for putting your time and efforts in.

Answer (score 2):

Initially you have 5 rows. You add a new row to the table, lets say using addRowsAtIndexPaths: method. At this point, your table view will call its datasource methods, as it needs to add this new cell.

But, probably your still returning number of rows as 5 (and not 6), from your datasource methods, which resulted in inconsistency (as table view expects 6 rows and you are still returning 5 rows)

So, lets say when the table view calls cellForRowAtIndexPath: method for the newly created cell (row = 5), it could crash because you must be doing something as:

```
[yourDatasourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The above statement would result in crash, as indexPath.row is 5 and your array still has 5 objects in it (index 0 to 4). Thus objectAtIndex:5 results in crash.

Comment: This is most likely the answer. In summary, return the right number from `numberOfRows` after you call `insert` or `delete`.

Comment: Hey guys... Thanks for the comments... I have sorted out the probelm... Please find my answer below